# Hierarchical complex type in Web Api ODATA Controller

Tags: c#, odata

I have the following complex type to return from an Web Api ODATA controller:

```
public class TreeItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TreeItem> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the controller method:

```
// GET: odata/TreeItems
public IHttpActionResult GetTreeItems(ODataQueryOptions<TreeItem> queryOptions)
        {
            // validate the query.
            try
            {
                queryOptions.Validate(_validationSettings);
            }
            catch (ODataException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }

            var treeItems = new List<TreeItem>();
            treeItems.Add(new TreeItem() { Id = 1, Name = "Geleiding", Children = new List<TreeItem>() { new TreeItem(){ Id=4, Name="Item1-1", Children=new List<TreeItem>()} } });
            treeItems.Add(new TreeItem() { Id = 2, Name = "Item 2", Children = new List<TreeItem>() });
            treeItems.Add(new TreeItem() { Id = 3, Name = "Item 3", Children = new List<TreeItem>() });
            return Ok<IEnumerable<TreeItem>>(treeItems);
        }
```

In WebApiCOnfig:
builder.EntitySet("TreeItems").EntityType.ComplexProperty(c => c.Children);

When I go to this URL: http://localhost:50997/odata/TreeItems

I get this response:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:50997/odata/$metadata#TreeItems","value":[
    {
      "Children":{
        "Capacity":4
      },"Id":1,"Name":"Geleiding"
    },{
      "Children":{
        "Capacity":0
      },"Id":2,"Name":"Item 2"
    },{
      "Children":{
        "Capacity":0
      },"Id":3,"Name":"Item 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I get the Children list to show completely including all levels it may have?

$expand=Children does not work, says Children is not a navigational property.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ODataQueryOptions<TreeItem> queryOptions` from the action, add the [EnableQuery] on the action.

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetTreeItems()
{
 ...
}
```

Thanks.

Besides, your title is not correct. `TreeItem` is built as entity type by you, not complex type. Entity type and complex type are both structural type, but entity type must have key, while complex type needn't.

===============Iteration 2 ===============

1. As I said, you can't explicitly mapping the `Children` as complex type. So,

the following code is unnecessary:

```
builder.EntitySet("TreeItems").EntityType.ComplexProperty(c => c.Children);
```

If you are using `ODataConventionModelBuilder`, just remove the `.ComplexProperty()` function call.

2. You can use `$levels` to expand sub levels of Children. I build a [sample project](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/tree/master/DollarLevelSample) that you can refer to, in which I give four queries:

   http://localhost/odata/TreeItems

   http://localhost/odata/TreeItems?$expand=Children

   http://localhost/odata/TreeItems?$expand=Children($levels=2)

   http://localhost/odata/TreeItems?$expand=Children($levels=max)

All queries will return different results (I made some changes in the controller). You can easily run this console application to check the result. I do think you can find what you want.

Please let me know if you have any concern about the project.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. However, your proposal does not change anything, I do not get any children passed back. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Your changes did give me a tree with children! I did have to use the query http://localhost:50997/odata/TreeItems?$expand=Children/Children/Children . Your level parameter is not supported when I try it. Do I need to do something else to get to use it?

Comment: Think I need to install a newer version of the ODATA WebAPI: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/09/12/announcing-the-release-of-web-api-odata-5-3.aspx